# Compute $\iint x^2 dx dy$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How to calculate $$\iint x^2 dx dy$$
Over $\{(x,y): x^2+2y+y^2\leq 3, x^2-2y+y^2\leq 3\}$ in polar coordinates for example?
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @zkutch You can here post your answer.

Comment: Titles that are 100% math markup are not preferred.  (As an easily-observed reason: try right-clicking on the title and opening it in a new tab.)

Comment: At the risk of telling you what you already know, askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could edit your question to add any of the following. Where did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think I know how to solve it in Decart's coordinates, but I don't know how to do this in polar coordinates. This is a question I posted and then deleted it, I didn't know how to undelete question, therefore I posted only the part I didn't know how to solve.

Comment: @alans. I see, that answer already is written and accepted, so you have full decision. Unique, that I would like to add is that outgoing from symmetry with respect to $OX$ and $OY$ it's enough to calculate area in first quadrant ($x,y\gt 0$) and multiply it by $4$.  Here is enough "shifted" polar coordinate already used by Vajra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll let you complete the calculations.
The domain of integration is $E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+(y+1)^2\le4,x^2+(y-1)^2\le 4\}$, so you have to consider the section defined by the two circles of radius $2$ and centers in $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$.
Now I suggest you to calculate two integrals using the polar coordinates centered in $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$:
$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta-1 \end{cases},\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta+1 \end{cases}$$
with the angle $\theta\in[7\pi/6,11\pi/6]$ and $r\in\bigg[\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta},2\bigg]$ for the first case and really similar for the second coordinate system. Now you can compute
$$\iint_E x^2dxdy=\iint_{(\tilde E)^-}r^3\cos^2\theta drd\theta+\iint_{(\tilde E)^+}r^3\cos^2\theta drd\theta$$
where $\tilde E^-$ and $\tilde E^+$ are the two sets defined by the two coordinate systems.[image]